# URLConnection: какое значние лучше задать для setConnectTimeout и setReadTimeout?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
Интересует вопрос, какие значения для таймаута ожидания соединения и чтения данных лучше всего выставить?
Пользователя равно могут использовать как быстрый  WIFI, так и медленный мобильный интернет.
Скачиваются  файлы размером более 2МБ.

Answer (score 1):

По моему лучше определить тип соединения и в зависимости от этого ставить таймаут.
[Обнаружить тип сетевого подключения на Android](http://www.answerstop.org/question/574845/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)

Comment: хорошо, какие таймауты лучше выставлять для разных типов соединений?

Comment: не задумывался над этим, но как вариант настраивать на маршрутизаторе разную скорость интернета и проверять научным тыком, после выбрать что то среднее

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, timeout выставляется на время, которое соединение не отвечает. То есть, если поставить timeout 2 секунды, а сам файл будет качаться 10, то ничего не оборвётся.

Comment: я знаю для чего нужны таймауты и как они работают, мне интересны "best practices" умных людей :)